# Spring redisTemplate delete by query

Tags: spring, redis

I am using spring redistemplate

```
@Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, RedisToken> redisTemplate;

RedisToken => token | id | date
```

I can delete by OBJECT_KEY . How can I delete by query? Or I need to find all records and then delete it.

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().delete(RedisToken.OBJECT_KEY, key);
```

I want to delete by id . Multiple records with ids.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete multiple records in a hash by the same function, you can pass your keys to function as below (for example three keys):
`redisTemplate.opsForHash().delete(RedisToken.OBJECT_KEY, "1","2","3");`.

Comment: did you find this helpful!!?